# Aggregate data frame in R based on first column which are strings

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe like this. I would like to aggregate each column(sum) value based on the individual role of the first column. I have tried for a while but I don't know how to handle it when the first column are strings. And if I could get the last row with total sums, that would be a plus. However, I will be happy already if I could get aggregate values of each roles. How can I do it? Thank you!

df:

```
 profession      apple    banana   grape   pear
  teacher          1       0         1       0
  student          0       1         0       1
  student          1       0         1       1 
  journalist       1       1         0       1
  teacher          0       0         0       1
  bus driver       1       0         0       0
  journalist       1       0         1       1
  bus driver       0       0         0       1
  teacher          1       0         0       1
```

output:

```
  profession      apple    banana   grape   pear

   teacher          2       0         1       2
   student          1       1         1       2
   journalist       2       1         2       2
   bus driver       1       0         0       1
   sum              6       2         4       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to do a group by `sum` by 'profession', then add a row with the `colSums`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>%
     group_by(profession) %>% 
     summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
     add_row(profession = 'sum', !!! colSums(.[-1]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  profession apple banana grape  pear
#  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 bus driver     1      0     0     1
#2 journalist     2      1     1     2
#3 student        1      1     1     2
#4 teacher        2      0     1     2
#5 sum            6      2     3     7
```

---

Or use `adorn_totals` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
df %>%
      group_by(profession) %>% 
      summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .groups = 'drop')  %>% 
      adorn_totals()
#  profession apple banana grape pear
#  bus driver     1      0     0    1
#  journalist     2      1     1    2
#    student     1      1     1    2
#    teacher     2      0     1    2
#    Total     6      2     3    7
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(profession = c("teacher", "student", "student", 
"journalist", "teacher", "bus driver", "journalist", "bus driver", 
"teacher"), apple = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), banana = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), grape = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), pear = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @akrun. Can you show me the output like a dataframe? I run it on my code, but I could not get the exact output. I guess i did something wrong. Thank you

Comment: @smoothy can you try now.  I did updated the post

Comment: Thank you@akrun. I just updated my question. Actually some professions in my first column have one space, I don't know if that 's cause the error. But I can see from your output, it should work. I just need to retry it. Thank you!

Comment: @smoothy I updated the data you showed.  It is giving the expected

Answer (score 1):

it can be done by data.table

```
setDT(df)[,.(apple = sum(apple), banana = sum(banana),
           grape = sum(grape), pear = sum(pear)), .(profession)
```

Comment: Thank you @Azat. I like your solution as well. The only problem is my dataset has too many columns. But I will definitely try it in the future:)